# 2006 Jeep Grand Cherokee 3.7L Auto Transmission Issue Shifting

Tags: transmission, jeep, cherokee

Went over railroad tracks and the dash lit up like a christmas tree.  Replaced wheel hubs, speed sensors, trans fluid, plugs, coils.

Service engine light is off and now the car feels limp and wont shift out of 3rd.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check all the wiring and sensors or the 'box and engine? How fast did you go over? It sounds like you hit this hard and you could have damaged or broken many items...

Comment: Did wiring harness as well.  Wasnt a hard hit more bumpy.  Going thru forums this year Jeep has some ig issues im now learning.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could just comment this but my score is too low here.

You may just need to clear codes in the pcm (engine and trans memories). 
Your CEL may not be on but there could still be stored "history" codes. These can keep the trans and engine in limp mode even when not active. You'll need a decent scanner to do it most likely.